# Given an int variable status, write a switch statement that prints out, on a line by itself, the appropriate label from the above list based on status

Tags: java

HTTP is the protocol that governs communications between web servers and web clients (i.e. browsers). Part of the protocol includes a status code returned by the server to tell the browser the status of its most recent page request. Some of the codes and their meanings are listed below:

200, OK (fulfilled)
403, forbidden
404, not found
500, server error

Given an int variable status, write a switch statement that prints out, on a line by itself, the appropriate label from the above list based on status.

This is what I have for my code but it's still not working and I am unsure as to why.

```
switch ( status ){
case 200: System.out.println("OK(fulfilled)");
break;
case 403: System.out.println("forbidden");
break;
case 404: System.out.println("not found");
break;
case 500: System.out.println("server error");
break;
```

}

The error I get is "The value of _stdout is incorrect."

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: Do you get an error? Add a default case and check if the default case is getting executed. Try debugging or printing and see if the status is actually having one of the defined case values

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question. The code you are showing does not even use the name that the error message is showing!

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to post your entire source code? 
Have you tried using the default case as shown below?

```
public void run() {

    //enter a test case here to see if your console prints the output:
    int status = readInt("Enter case here: ");


    switch ( status ){
    case 200: System.out.println("OK(fulfilled)");
    break;
    case 403: System.out.println("forbidden");
    break;
    case 404: System.out.println("not found");
    break;
    case 500: System.out.println("server error");
    break;

//Try the default case here:
    default: 
        break;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured out you're supposed to use `System.out.print("")`, because it's supposed to be entered on a line by itself.